# Inserir FXML dentro de Scroll Pane e passar dados para controller

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Meu sistema consiste em uma tela principal, a qual possui um scroll-pane que estou populando com uma lista de outras cenas FXML, código do qual peguei em um exemplo na internet, segue o código:

```
@FXML
private Label label;

@FXML
private VBox pnl_scroll;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(MouseEvent event) {
    refreshNodes();
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    refreshNodes();
}

private void refreshNodes() {
    pnl_scroll.getChildren().clear();

    Node[] nodes = new Node[15];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        try {
            nodes[i] = (Node) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Item.fxml"));
            pnl_scroll.getChildren().add(nodes[i]);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

O problema é, preciso setar os dados de cada item.fxml do scroll-pane antes de adiciona-los, como posso fazer isso?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Tu pode pegar o controller dessas views da seguinte forma:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Item.fxml"));
ItemController controller = loader.getController();
Node root = loader.load();
```

Com isso tu pode chamar os métodos deles através da variável "controller".

Uma outra coisa que tu pode fazer é usar o "fx:include" direto no arquivo ".fxml". Já tentei inseri-los pelo scene builder mas nunca consegui, apesar disso depois que tu inclui eles no arquivo o scene builder já mostra tua view principal com as outras incluídas. Desta forma no arquivo ficaria assim:

```
<VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0">
    <children>
        <fx:include fx:id="itemId" source="Item.fxml"/>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Para acessar o controller desta view, por exemplo, é só tu declarar uma variável com o id do Node mais a palavra "Controller" no final. Ficaria assim neste caso:

```
@FXML
private AchorPane itemId;

@FXML
private ItemController itemIdController;
```

Para mais informações sobre tu pode acessar [este link](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements).

Comment: A princípio, estou conseguindo acessar os métodos do meu controller. Fiz um método de teste no controler do item, que escreve no console, mas dá NullPointerException na hora da execução.

Comment: Já estou conseguindo acessar os métodos do outro controller, mas não consigo setar os valores das labels, mesmo criando os getters e setters.